# Does Java have a limit on loop cycles?

Tags: java, for-loop

I solved the Project Euler problem #14 https://projecteuler.net/problem=14 on Java, but when I run it in Powershell, it stops iterating at exactly i = 113383 every time. I rewrote the solution on python, and it works perfectly fine, albeit slowly. According to my (identical) python solution, the answer is that the number that produces the longest chain is 837799 and the chain is 524 operations long.

Why does the Java solution not finish the for-loop? Is there some kind of limit in Java on how long it can stay in a loop? I cannot come up with any other explanation. Java code below. I wrote the System.out.println(i) there just to see what is going on.

```
class ProjectEuler14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int largestNumber = 1;
        int largestChain = 1;
        int currentNumber;
        int chainLength;

        for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            currentNumber = i;
            chainLength = 0;

            while (currentNumber != 1) {
                if (currentNumber % 2 == 0) currentNumber /= 2;
                else currentNumber = 3 * currentNumber + 1;
                chainLength++;
            }

            if (chainLength > largestChain) {
                largestChain = chainLength;
                largestNumber = i;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n\nThe number under million that produces the "
                           + "longest chain is " + largestNumber +
                           " and the chain's length is " + largestChain);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it is also performing division

Comment: I'm not sure why belwood deleted their answer, but it is definitely due to integer overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. I wanted to make it more specific.

Comment: Yes! I changed all the int types to long and now it gets all the way through and gives the same answer as the python solution. Annoying that there is no error message or anything, it just freezes and I have to ctrl + C out. Add an answer please and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: There is no error message because the integer overflow is not an error in Java, but in your code it triggers an infinite loop in your `while` loop.

Comment: Just to point out, the fact you got stuck in an infinite loop shows that java does not have a limit on loop cycles. They can go for as long as the computer is running.

Comment: the problema is that when i > 113382 the currentNumber division produce a negative value and the currentNumber never have value 1 and never end the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `for` loop. It's the `while` loop. The condition `currentNumber != 1` is always true; forever.

In java, an `int` is specifically defined as an integral number between `-2^31` and `+2^31 -1`, inclusive, and operations 'roll over'. try it!

```
int x = 2^31 -1;
x++;
System.out.println(x);
```

this prints a large negative number (in fact, precisely `-2^31`).

It's happening in your algorithm, and that's why it never finishes.

A trivial solution is to 'upgrade' to longs; they are just as fast, really (yay 64-bit processors!) and use 64 bits, thus giving them a range of `-2^63` to `+2^63-1`.

Python sort of scales up its numbers into slowness silently, java makes different choices (and, for crypto and other purposes, that rollover thing is in fact desired).

If you want to go even further, you can always use `BigInteger`, which grows as much as you need forever (becoming slower and taking more memory as it goes).

To know rollover occurred, the 3* operation would then result in a number that is lower than the original, and you can check for that:

replace:

```
else currentNumber = 3 * currentNumber + 1;
```

with:

```
else {
    int newNumber = currentNumber * 3 + 1;
    if (newNumber < currentNumber) throw new IllegalStateException("Overflow has occurred; 3 * " + currentNumber + " + 1 exceeds ints capacities.");
    currentNumber = newNumber;
}
```

and rerun it. You'll see your app nicely explain itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you recommend picking up the habit of always using long and double instead of int and float?

Comment: @asdfasdf The language is setup so that int is preferred over long unless you have a reason to need a long. Similar `double` is preferred over float, unless you have a specific reason.

Comment: @asdfasdf Strongly prefer 'int' and 'double' because the greater java ecosystem tends to be designed with those in mind. Deviate when you know these data types will not suffice. There are no easy answers; longs are limited too, so 'eh, Im going to never think about my needs, always use long, dont worry be happy!' doesn't work either - 64-bit allows for more numbers but it's still limited. doubles are still inaccurate. Less so than floats, but inaccurate nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The `currentNumber` is exceeding size of int, use long instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you hava problem overflow int.
Change int to long.

```
        long largestNumber = 1;
        long largestChain = 1;
        long currentNumber;
        long chainLength;

        for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++) {
            //System.out.println(i);
            currentNumber = i;
            chainLength = 0;

            while (currentNumber != 1) {
               
                //System.out.println("# = " + currentNumber);
                if (currentNumber % 2 == 0) {
                    currentNumber /= 2;
                } else {
                    currentNumber = (3 * currentNumber) +1 ;
                }
                chainLength++;
                
                 

            }

           // System.out.println("################################ " + i);
            if (chainLength > largestChain) {
                largestChain = chainLength;
                largestNumber = i;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n\nThe number under million that produces the "
                + "longest chain is " + largestNumber
                + " and the chain's length is " + largestChain);
```